# JQuery can't catch exception in the Restful web serverice.

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception

I am using JQuery get ajax call, it will not catch the exception in the callback function, In the java restful code, I force it to throw WebApplicationException exception, but Ajax call can't catch it, but it will show up in the Chrome console.

How to catch it in the ajax callback method ? thanks.

```
@GET
    @Path("getForm")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getForm() throws Exception {
    .....
        if (1==1) {
            System.out.println("---exeption ---");
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
       ....
    }
```

Ajax call

```
$.get('myurl', function(data, status) {
                alert(status); // not executed at all
                if (status === 'success') {
                    alert("success");
                }
                else {
                    alert("load failed");
                }
            });
```

In the Chrome console, I can see the error message: 401 (Unauthorized) .

Comment: You may want to use `fail` callback to track protocol errors. What you have is just the success callback. Checkout jquery docs..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback function in `$.get` is for success, you have to use `.fail` to handle failed request.

```
$.get('myurl', function(data) {
   // when success
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   // when fail
});
```

Comment: can you please show me how to use the 'textStatus' and 'errorThrown' ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get('myurl', function(data) {
                alert(data);

            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert(jqXHR.status);
});
```